# How to detect when RPSystemBroadcastPickerView is dismissed?

Tags: ios, swift, replaykit, rpsystembroadcastpickerview

In the app, I am using a `RPSystemBroadcastPickerView` to start a system-wide screen recording. I need to react to the user starting screen record or dismissing the shown picker view. In both cases, the system view gets dismissed.

I assumed that dismissing the system picker view will trigger a `viewDidAppear` event on the currently shown view controller. This does not happen. I tried to test if the `AppDelegate` triggers `applicationDidBecomeActive` or `applicationWillEnterForeground` - again without success (this are triggered when user open control center).

Does anyone have a suggestion what else to try?

Answer (score 0):

Before iOS 13: hook `RPSystemBroadcastPickerView` `containerVC`

iOS 14.0 or later: Monitor the focus and out-focus events of the app

Comment: I would add the reasoning why these plist values would be applicable in this case.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

You can achieve it indirectly using `Timer` and `UserDefaults`.

Start the `Timer` in ViewController from the main app and check for corresponding value change from `Broadcast Extension`.

```
 class SampleHandler: RPBroadcastSampleHandler {

    override func broadcastStarted(withSetupInfo setupInfo: [String : NSObject]?) {
       appGroupDefaults.set(true, forKey: appGroupUserDefaultKeys.isScreenBroadcastStarted.rawValue)
    }

    override func broadcastFinished() {
       appGroupDefaults.set(true, forKey: appGroupUserDefaultKeys.isScreenBroadcastStopped.rawValue)
    }
    
 }
```

Comment: this can test whether the broadcast is ongoing.. I need to know when the picker view is presented

Comment: using timer is bad ideal